# Reading and Writing to m4p

Tags: java, audio, file-io

I am specifically looking into making a program to find lyrics for songs and add it to them. I am however stuck on finding a way to extract the song and artist's name from the file and how to then write the lyrics to the file. I was thinking there must be some way that it is stored I assume that its some type of array but I have not come across anything

Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you ever try to use ID3 tag reader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by qrtt1 the info you want may be in the meta tags of the file. Fortunately there are several libraries out there to help with this. [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) seems to be fairly popular though.

> Jaudiotagger is the Audio Tagging library used by Jaikoz for tagging
>   data in Audio files. It currently fully supports Mp3, Mp4 (Mp4 audio,
>   M4a and M4p audio) Ogg Vorbis, Flac and Wma, there is limited support
>   for Wav and Real formats.